# Find the maximum value of a function with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The problem is the following.

Let $k>0$ be an integer and consider the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z,w)=x+y+z+w$.

Find the maximum value of $f$ under the constraint $x+y+z+w+x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=k$.

Looking at $f(x,y,z,w)$ like $1x+1y+1z+1w$ and applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality can be the right approach?

Comment: Yes, it's the right approach.

Comment: Let $f=f(x,y,z,w)$. I found $f^2\leq 4(k-f)$ from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. How do I need to go on? I'm a little bit confused :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the constraint, we have:
$$k+1 = \left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(w+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \ge0 $$
then we must have $k \ge -1$.

Applying the CS inequality:
$$k \ge f +\frac{1}{4} (f)^2$$
$$\iff\left(\frac{f}{2} +1 \right)^2  \le k+1$$
$$\iff -2(\sqrt{k+1} +1) \le  f  \le 2(\sqrt{k+1} -1)$$

We deduce that $f$ reaches its maximum at $2(\sqrt{k+1} -1)$ when $$x=y=z=t = \frac{f}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{k+1} -1}{2}$$

Comment: Ok, now I understand the procedure. Thank you very much!